# google app engine service ddos prevention

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare, ddos

How to prevent DDOS attack on the google app engine services ? I did check cloud armor, but they aren't applicable for app engine. Is there a way I can configure rate limiting rules for app engine services ?

Comment: CloudFlare is great for this.

Answer (score 4):

You must use Cloud Armor and indeed, it is not directly applicable to App Engine. You must deploy a [Load Balancer with a serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) that reference your App Engine service.

Then, you must set your App Engine accessible only from the Load Balancer (and no longer publicly accessible) by [controlling the ingress traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ingress-settings)

When it's done, you can activate Cloud Armor on the load balancer and play with it!

Comment: AppEngine has it's own load balancer right ? doesn't it come with default rate limiting or some kind of support to prevent DDOS ?

Comment: Nothing directly out of the box. You must add a layer in front. Google Cloud Load Balancer, Cloudflare or whatever, but not only App Engine